# Visual C++ Weird Compiler errors

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to make an encryptor/decryptor using XOR method.
I have done this before in Console C++, and I'm new to VC++, so I hope you can help me.
The encryption works like this:

```
key = 3
x = 5    // The item being encrypted

encryptedx = x ^ key // the "^" is XOR
```

So now, I want to make it in VC++, to make this look better that the Console window.
In the design view in VC++, I have two rich text boxes, key edit box, and some buttons to start the process.
It sounds really easy, but I get these errors:

```
------ Build started: Project: Encryptor, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Encryptor.cpp
1>c:\users\**********c*********ncryptor\encryptor\Form1.h(264): error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'System::String ^' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xstring(707): could be 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xstring(762): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xstring(767): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(const _Elem *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xstring(772): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(_Elem)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::string, System::String ^)'
1>c:\*******gl\*****cryptor\encryptor\Form1.h(281): error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'System::String ^' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xstring(707): could be 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xstring(762): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xstring(767): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(const _Elem *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xstring(772): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(_Elem)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::string, System::String ^)'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

And here is the code:

```
#include <string>
#include "crypFunc.cpp"

int key = 0;
char tempChar;
int stringLenght = 0;
string strBuffer = "";
using namespace std;

//
//
//
//
//



    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
             {
                 if(KeyBox->Text)
                 {
                 key =Convert::ToInt32(KeyBox->Text);
                 numericUpDown1->Value = key;
                 }


             }
//
//
//
//




private: System::Void EncryptButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
         {

             EncryptedBox->Text = ""; 

            strBuffer = DecryptedBox->Text;
             stringLenght = strBuffer.size();
             if( strBuffer.size() && key)
             {
             for(int i = 0; i < stringLenght; i++)
             {
                tempChar = encrypt(strBuffer[i], key);
                EncryptedBox->Text = EncryptedBox->Text + tempChar; 
             }
             }

         }


private: System::Void DecryptButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
         {
             DecryptedBox->Text = "";
             strBuffer = Convert::ToString(EncryptedBox->Text); 
             stringLenght = strBuffer.size();
             if( strBuffer.size() && key)
             {
                 for(int i = 0; i < stringLenght; i++)
                 {
                     tempChar = decrypt(strBuffer[i], key);
                     DecryptedBox->Text = DecryptedBox->Text + tempChar;
                 }
             }
         }
};
}
```

I really hope some of you can and want to help me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to assign a managed System::String^ object to a std::string. You would need to convert the System::String first:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b4az623(v=vs.80).aspx

Also, just to note, this isn't just standard "VC++". Your code is C++/CLI (which may be fine if that's what you're trying to do).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For VS2008 and newer, you can use `marshal_as`. Otherwise, see @Scott's answer.

```
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

String^ foo = "";
std::string bar = marshal_as<std::string>(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have gotten home and tried some stuff out for you.

I have this code working on my machine no problem.  Put together a little demo on how to convert from std::string to system::String^, as well as from system::string^ to std::string.

While reading, it seems that this is not the best idea going from std::string to system::string^.  You could read up on it if you like.

You will also need to set your Common Language Runtime support to /clr. Good Luck, and hope this helps!

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <msclr\marshal.h>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h> // you will only need one of these

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace msclr::interop;

int main() {
   //define our std::string
   string standardString = "Test String to Marshal";
   cout << "String before conversions: " << standardString<<endl;

   // convert std::string to system::string^ using marshalling
   String^ sysStringFromStandardString;
   sysStringFromStandardString = marshal_as<String^>( standardString );

   // convert system::string^ to std::string 
   string backToStdString;
   backToStdString = marshal_as<string>(sysStringFromStandardString);

   cout<< "String after converstion: "<<backToStdString<<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey. I understand your answer, and I did set it in my source code, but it still doesn't work.
can you please show me how you would solve this problem in System::Void EncryptButton_Click ?

Comment: Did it work for you?
I have the same errors all the time :/

Piece of code after your help:
'private: System::Void EncryptButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
   {
    std::string standString(""); 
    EncryptedBox->Text = gcnew String(standString.c_str())

   
    stringLenght = systemString.size();
    if(systemString != "" && key)
    {
    for(int i = 0; i < stringLenght; i++)
    {
    tempChar = encrypt(systemString[i], key);
    EncryptedBox->Text = EncryptedBox->Text + tempChar; '

Comment: I'm at work so I cant test ATM, we use java. I thought that was how I went about fixing an error like this in the past.

I can dig in a little deeper when I get home.